# js - youtube api - onstatechange not triggering

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am just trying to trigger an alert('test') at the end of a youtube video, worked well until today.

I just made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/264BB/, if anyone can check the code or faced the same issue please let me know, it would be nice.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert('test')
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        alert('test')
    }
}
```

If the trigger works well notice me too, maybe it is a browser specific problem.

Comment: this appears to be an issue only when YT is using the "default player", not HTML5. If I go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 and "Request the HTML5 player" on Firefox, I will start receiving events again. But of course I can't tell all of my users to do that.

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube API OnStateChange Listener Stops Working After Switch SRC Attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021429/youtube-api-onstatechange-listener-stops-working-after-switch-src-attr)

You should check there, the guys is using the same API and code and it looks good.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: the solution mentionned in the jsfiddle is not working... could that be my browser ?

Comment: Which browser are you using ? try with googlechrome, it's probably the best for youtube and google services.